# Proof or counterexample of the following inequality

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality

I want to prove the following inequality for $n\geq 4$:
$$-\frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\log\left(1+c\left(a\cos(\frac{2\pi i}{n})+b\sin(\frac{2\pi i}{n})\right)\right)\left(a\cos(\frac{2\pi i}{n})+b\sin(\frac{2\pi i}{n})\right)^2\geq 0. $$
Here $0<c<1$ and $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ such that the term in $\log$ are greater than $0$.

By graphing the left hand side I notice this inequality does not hold for $n=3$:

**n=3 for some c in (0,1) and a,b in circle region:**

[image]

But for $n\geq 4$ and it looks like a convex function:

**n=5 for some c in (0,1) and a,b in circle region:**

[image]

Comment: You may use \left( \right) sometimes.

Comment: Let $s_j = \sin(2 \pi j/n + \phi)$, then we need to prove that
$$\sum_{j = 0}^{n - 1} s_j^2 \ln(1 + r s_j) \leq 0.$$
We can use the estimate $\ln(1 + r s_j) \leq r s_j$
and show that $\sum_{j = 0}^{n - 1} s_j^3 = 0$ for any $n > 3$.